# Login failure with jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have created login page using servlet and JSP. It works fine for first login. But after logout if I tried for another login servlet gets executed as I can see it in url but no output can be seen.

**validate.java**

```
package servlets;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class validate extends HttpServlet {

/**
 *
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse 
 response) 
  throws ServletException,IOException
{
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 try{
 String name=request.getParameter("email");
 String pass=request.getParameter("password");
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\SQLITE\\ MYDATABASE.DB");
 Statement s=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs;
  rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE EMAIL_ID='"+name+"' ");

  if(rs.next())
  {

 if( (name.trim().equals(rs.getString(3).trim())) && (   
   pass.trim().equals(rs.getString(6).trim()) )  )
{

 //New session creation
  HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
  //setting attribute on session
  session.setAttribute("user",name);
 //send request to Welcome.jsp page

  RequestDispatcher view =request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");

  view.forward(request, response);

}
else
 {
  out.println("<div style='font-size:30px; color:red'>" +"Userid and password does not          matched "+"</div>");
   RequestDispatcher view =request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");

 view.include(request, response);
     }
  }
 else
  {
   out.println("<div style='font-size:30px; color:red'>"+"Please fill userid and password"+"</div>");
   RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
   view.include(request, response);
  }
    }catch(Exception e){}
 finally{
   out.close();
  }
  }
 }
```

**logout.java**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class logout extends HttpServlet {

/**
 *
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 try {
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
out.println("<div style='float:left;font-size:25px;'>"+"click here to "
   +"<a href='login.html'>login</a></div>");
out.println("<h1 align='center'>"+"Logout Sucessfully..."+"</h1>");
 }finally {            
 out.close();
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Post the code in your question that's been implemented.

Comment: How can we know without codes?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor  here is the code for servlet. Please help me...

Comment: You should check if session id is the same for both servlets. I think they are different for Login and Logout servlet. You should pass JSESSIONID cookie value to logout servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "no output can be seen" because there is an exception and you ignore it in your code:

```
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Try adding some logging inside the catch block to see if it is the case.